# Adding to an existing XML file, I get a forward slash placed at the end of the opening element tag

Tags: xml, vb.net

new to XML and having trouble adding in new nodes to an existing XML file.

Here's how the XML file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <UserName-1>
    <Private-1>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
      <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
    </Private-1>
    <Public-1>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
      <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
    </Public-1>
  </UserName-1>
  <UserName-2>
    <Private-2>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-2>33333</PrivateFtpAccountId-2>
      <PrivatePassword-2>test3</PrivatePassword-2>
    </Private-2>
    <Public-2>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-2>44444</PublicFtpAccountId-2>
      <PublicPassword-2>test4</PublicPassword-2>
    </Public-2>
  </UserName-2>
</Users>
```

I want to add in these following the last grouping.

```
<UserName-3>
    <Private-3>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
      <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
    </Private-3>
    <Public-3>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
      <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
    </Public-3>
</UserName-3>
```

After running my code below I produce this XML file (I'm replacing the original):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <UserName-1>
    <Private-1>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-1>11111</PrivateFtpAccountId-1>
      <PrivatePassword-1>test1</PrivatePassword-1>
    </Private-1>
    <Public-1>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-1>22222</PublicFtpAccountId-1>
      <PublicPassword-1>test2</PublicPassword-1>
    </Public-1>
  </UserName-1>
  <UserName-2>
    <Private-2>
      <PrivateFtpAccountId-2>33333</PrivateFtpAccountId-2>
      <PrivatePassword-2>test3</PrivatePassword-2>
    </Private-2>
    <Public-2>
      <PublicFtpAccountId-2>44444</PublicFtpAccountId-2>
      <PublicPassword-2>test4</PublicPassword-2>
    </Public-2>
  </UserName-2>
  <UserName-3 />
  <Private-3>
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
    <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
  </Private-3>
  <Public-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
  </Public-3>
</Users>
```

But having trouble...

```
  Named <UserName-3 /> instead of <UserName-3>   <--- where is the / at the end coming from in the beginning tag?
  Did not indent properly
  No closing tag for this element
```

My code in a console app:

```
    Dim strId As String
    Dim strPrivateFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPrivatePassword As String
    Dim strPublicFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPublicPassword As String

    strPrivateFtpAcctId = "55555"
    strPrivatePassword = "test5"
    strPublicFtpAcctId = "66666"
    strPublicPassword = "test6"
    strId = "3"

    ' Setting these variables above for now but they would actually be coming in as arguments and hence will be dynamically set at runtime.

    Dim xEle As XElement = XElement.Load("MyGoodXMLforadding.xml")
    xEle.Add(New XElement("UserName-" & strId))
    xEle.Add(New XElement("Private-" & strId, New XElement("PrivateFtpAccountId-" & strId, strPrivateFtpAcctId), New XElement("PrivatePassword-" & strId, srPrivatePassword)))
    xEle.Add(New XElement("Public-" & strId, New XElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId, strPublicFtpAcctId), New XElement("PublicPassword-" & strId, "test6")))

    ' Save in place.
    xEle.Save("MyGoodXMLforadding.xml")
```

I even hardcoded a value for this:

```
    xEle.Add(New XElement("UserName-3"))
```

and I still get the same thing.

Regards...Dan

Answer (score 1):

In the XML this notation means the element is empty, it is a *self closing* tag:

```
<UserName-3 />
```

It is logically similar to the following empty element, however an empty element is much longer syntax:

```
<UserName-3></UserName-3>
```

XML editors that have have auto-complete and syntax highlighting will initially create your elements as self-closing because it keeps the XML valid while you define attributes, this optimises the user experience, but also means if you are less likely to forget to close the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should've added `<Private-X>` and `<Public-X>` to `<UserName-X>` instead of to the root element (`xEle` in your code) :

```
........
Dim username = New XElement("UserName-" & strId)
username.Add(New XElement("Private-" & strId, ....))
username.Add(New XElement("Public-" & strId, ....))
xEle.Add(username)
........
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for the response.

I added that code as suggested

I now do not get an opening tag, just a closing tag. And it is still not formed correctly.

Comment: This is it. Notice the the space and forward slash following the name.

  <Private-3>
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
    <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
  </Private-3>
  <Public-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
  </Public-3>
  <UserName-3 />

Comment: I then added 1 more line of code right after the 1st line.

        Dim username = New XElement("UserName-" & strId)
        xEle.Add(username)
        xEle.Add(New XElement("Private-" & strId, New XElement("PrivateFtpAccountId-" & strId, strPrivateFtpAcctId), New XElement("PrivatePassword-" & strId, strPrivatePassword)))
        xEle.Add(New XElement("Public-" & strId, New XElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId, strPublicFtpAcctId), New XElement("PublicPassword-" & strId, "test6")))
        xEle.Add(username)

Comment: I now get the opening tag too. But it too is not formed correctly and the nodes beneath it do not indent.

Comment: What could be causing the tags to be badly formed?

Comment: I tried hard-coding the value and get the same result.
 
        Dim username = New XElement("UserName-3")
        xEle.Add(username)
        xEle.Add(New XElement("Private-" & strId, New XElement("PrivateFtpAccountId-" & strId, strPrivateFtpAcctId), New XElement("PrivatePassword-" & strId, strPrivatePassword)))
        xEle.Add(New XElement("Public-" & strId, New XElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId, strPublicFtpAcctId), New XElement("PublicPassword-" & strId, "test6")))
        xEle.Add(username)

Comment: <UserName-3 />
  <Private-3>
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
    <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
  </Private-3>
  <Public-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
  </Public-3>
  <UserName-3 />

Comment: Did you notice that I suggested to add `New XElement("Private-" & strId, ....)` & `New XElement("Public-" & strId, ....)` to `username` instead of to `xEle`??? Please, look at the code sample closely. One more: never throw codes & XML in comment. Edit your question and post it there properly formatted

Comment: Ok..sorry about that...knew it was hard to read. Did not know I was to EDIT the question to reply....but now I do. I did notice..but messed up. I fixed it to add to username.  Works perfect...thanks so much.